# Creating event lists using nodequeue, static pages and dynamic dates

Tags: datetime

I'm new to Drupal, with some familiarity in other CMSes. I'm currently attempting to create a series of event lists, and have met up with a few issues. The number of modules available for the system are confusing my Googling, as terminology isn't uniform across the web and I'm picking up information for everything but what I want. From reading in StackOverflow, I gather it's a common problem with Drupal. I'm looking for recommended resources or perhaps more direct help - advice on whether to learn the system fully despite this being such a simple/small job would be useful as well.

**In summary:**

Need an online system to create itineraries, lists of events containing location information and dates that are specific to unique clients/users. Employees access the backend, assemble an itinerary and provide a link to customers with an appropriately formatted, final page/document. Drupal is a CMS that is potentially going to be used for a future website, and "location information" would be a duplication of web content - this system would make for a neat way of populating the website with content whilst the main frontend is being developed.

**What I need**

- locations are created as static nodes (pages)
- access the backend with an interface that allows for the selection of these location nodes and compiles them into an ordered list
- each node, despite being static, is associated with a date field (start and end) specific to each ordered list
- lists are unique and independent, using the same static content to fill description fields but able to be linked with specific date information

**Where I'm currently at**

- locations are created as static nodes (pages)
- the itinerary is a nodequeue, where an employee creates a new one, adds location nodes and can control the order without technical know-how
- display using Views, using unique URL per list
- trying to find a way to relate the unique nodequeue with a pair of dates for each location
- been playing around with custom content types/custom fields, but don't know how to define the relationship between the static/dynamic content
- using Date API for javascript calendar pop-up in these custom fields

Any help would be much appreciated! I've tried to word the concept clearly here, and am  looking for a friendly pointer in the right direction. Even so much as the appropriate keywords so I can find tutorials would help - been a few long hours of head scratching.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Reworded on Drupal forums, might help here.

I'm trying to create unique itineraries that are specific to either a user or URL. An itinerary is a unique order of events, each associated with a start+end date (specific to each user). Events are stored as static pages and can be on any day.

For clarity: create a list of pre-existing static nodes (descriptions of events) that can be arranged in any order. Each event needs to be associated with a user/URL-specific date in this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, adding my solution for the collective knowledge!

- Created each location as an individual page (appropriately classified by taxonomy/etc. for site navigation)
- Assigned the desired custom fields, most ended being display hidden
- Created new content type, "itinerary-location-reference", using module "Reference" (for D7)
- Within this content type, assigned custom fields for dates/visitor name/etc.
- One of the custom fields needs to be a node reference
- Referenced the location

This creates two nodes that are linked...one is the static location content, the other a node containing date/personal information. I then added this overall reference node to my nodequeues. Done.

I can see a few issues down the road regarding number of entries into the database, but apparently Drupal's good for a few million, so fingers crossed!